# Should I use Rails 3 or Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I heard Rails 3 is almost ready to be released from beta, meaning its a stable version. But of course the real date still unknown.

So I'm looking for advice from a good RoR developer. Do you think I should learn and use Rails 3 RC version or use Rails 2.3.8?  If I use the RC version now will it be hard to upgrade to the stable Rails 3 version?

Is there a decent RoR developer out there than can offer some guidance?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026912/rails-2-3-4-vs-rails-3-book-beginner-in-ror/3027463#3027463

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what a rock developer (!) is, but I'd recommend going with Rails 3 rather than Rails 2.x. Rails 3 represents the future direction of Ruby on Rails, so it's worth getting up to speed with it as soon as you can. To be frank, Rails 2.x is now an evolutionary dead-end. There shouldn't be any significant changes between the Rails 3 Release Candidate and the final version.

The barriers to adopting Rails 3 you might encounter are:

- its availability on your production stack
- plugin/gem compatibility

For the first issue, I know that the popular Heroku for example are [tracking the Rails 3 beta releases pretty closely](http:///blog.heroku.com/archives/2010/6/15/rails_3_beta_4_on_heroku/). Regarding the second issue, not all plugins or gems are compatible at the moment, but **a lot of the most popular ones are**. If there are specific plugins or gems that you need to use then [check here](http://railsplugins.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get a project off the ground **now**, then by all means go with Rails 2.3.8. It's the safe choice.

There are some significant changes in Rails 3. Some tools will be available to help you upgrade. But no automated tool will ever completely convert your 2.3.8 application to Rails 3. It's hard to tell how much effort is involved, that really depends on your application.

That said, if you are new, learning, and not expecting to release anything for several months, Rails 3 is the right choice. By the time your grok Rails and have something in production, Rails 3 will likely have stabilized, and nobody will be looking back.

Answer (score 2):

Use rails 3!!  The RC is still in the pipeline, but it's more or less good to go and you won't need to make any code changes when the final release is made

Here are some reasonable resources to get you started with it

1. http://railscasts.com
2. http://www.railsdispatch.com/
3. http://www.teachmetocode.com/
4. http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts/rails3/